# How can I merge 2 or more similar mysql row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I have table tables in MySQL named "temporarytransaction" ans "tbltransaction"

temporarytransaction and tbltransaction has 3 columns named "customer", "service rendered" and "date"

so for example temporarytransaction has 3 values

> Nathan | Men's Cut    | 2017-09-23
>
> Nathan  | Nail Art    | 2017-09-23
>
> Nathan  | Massage     | 2017-09-23

what I need to do was merge or concat the "service rendered" in the tbltransaction.
is it possible to save it like this in tbltransaction?

> Nathan  | Men's Cut,Nail Art,Massage  | 2017-09-23

I had try this but it doesn't save that way

```
INSERT INTO tbltransaction (customer,service,date) SELECT customer,service,date FROM temporarytransaction;";
```

Comment: Mureinik's answer is correct, but I'd like to add the link to the [GROUP_CONCAT documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). You even could arrange that you only see *distinct* services or order the services in the concatenated string in ascending or descending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could aggregate the `service` values with [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
INSERT INTO tbltransaction (customer,service,date)
SELECT      customer, GROUP_CONCAT(service SEPARATOR ','), date 
FROM        temporarytransaction
GROUP BY    customer, date
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your group column is `customer`, you can execute the following query:

```sql
INSERT INTO `tbltransaction` (`customer`, `service`, `date`)
SELECT
  `temporarytransaction`.`customer`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT `temporarytransaction`.`service`
    ORDER BY `temporarytransaction`.`service`
  ) `service`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT `temporarytransaction`.`date`
    ORDER BY `temporarytransaction`.`date`
  ) `date`
FROM (
  SELECT 'Nathan' `customer`,
         'Men\'s Cut' `service`,
         '2017-09-23' `date`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Nathan',
         'Nail Art',
         '2017-09-23'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Nathan',
         'Massage',
         '2017-09-23'
) `temporarytransaction`
GROUP BY
  `temporarytransaction`.`customer`;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nJS392A1fwftmWXtgqvAns/1).

Remember that the result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) system variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tt.customer,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( tt1.service) FROM temporarytransaction tt1 WHERE  tt1.customer=tt.customer AND tt1.date=tt.date) AS service, tt.date FROM temporarytransaction tt GROUP BY tt.customer, tt.date
```